# Preventing hardcoded javascript event

Tags: javascript, events

```
<select onchange="window.location='/staff/add_combo.php?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&amp;ipp=2';return false" class="paginate">
```

Is there any way to prevent onchange event on this element?

Comment: How about simply changing it? It's not clear what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Remove the onchange attribute from the element?

Comment: i simply want to remove the onchange event..the link is being generated by one of php class, i dont feel like changing the class just for the sake to remove the onchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to remove the handler permanently or temporarily?

```
//grabs first select on page
var mySelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

// permanently
mySelect.onchange = function(){};//noop

//temporarily
var toggle = true;
var orig  = mySelect.onchange;
mySelect.onchange = function(){
  if(toggle) toggle = false;
  else orig.call(mySelect);
};
```

The permanent version just blows out the existing handler.

The temporary version saves the original onchange handler and calls it depending on some other state in the application (in this case the "toggle" variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the event from firing on a single occasion, but you can unset it by assigning `null` to the element's `onchange` property:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

If by preventing you mean removing the event listener, than yes.
Just use the [removeEventListener](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)() method.

document.getElementById("mySelect").removeEventListener('onchange', function(), false);

The answer By Any E should work as well, it's the [traditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) way of handling it.

Comment: This isn't technically correct; in his original example, that needs to be removed as an Attribute.